# How do I open a visual studio 2010 express project in visual studio 2010 professional?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I started development on a project using VS 2010 Express. I now have installed VS 2010 Professional and would like to finish my development in there.

My problem is that when I try to open the solution using 2010 Pro, I get an error which says:

> One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly. Please see the output window for details.

Then I click 'ok' and I see that nearly of of my projects in that solution have not been loaded. The output window says:

> C:\path\SlateStone.csproj : error  : The project file 'C:\path\SlateStone.csproj' cannot be opened.
>
> The project type is not supported by this installation.
>
> C:\path\SlateStone.Admin.csproj : error  : The project file 'C:\path\SlateStone.Admin.csproj' cannot be opened.
>
> The project type is not supported by this installation.
>
> C:\path\SlateStone.Rss.Plug.csproj : error  : The project file 'C:\path\SlateStone.Rss.Plug.csproj' cannot be opened.
>
> The project type is not supported by this installation.
>
> C:[ath\SlateStone.News.Plug.csproj : error  : The project file 'C:\path\SlateStone.News.Plug.csproj' cannot be opened.
>
> The project type is not supported by this installation.

How can I get my projects from 2010 Express to load in 2010 Pro???? These projects are just MVC.

Comment: After looking in my new project options for 2010 pro, I've noticed that MVC3 is not an option. Only MVC2. Do I need to install MVC3 again? (It was already installed when I installed vs2010express.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing one of the add-ons / updates from Visual studio.  By your comment, it sounds like you need to reinstall MVC3 (there was a partial update of this in SP1, which could be where your issue lies)

Otherwise you shouldn't have any issues opening projects initially created in express in the other 'better' versions (you just might have the problem if you add an non-supported project type and then try to open it in Express later on.)